# How to change the drawer container color of ModalNavigationDrawer in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I just updated material3 dependency to:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha16"
```

And:

```
drawerContainerColor = Color.Red
```

Doesn't work anymore. I tried to set:

```
scrimColor = Color.Red
```

But the color is not changed? How to change the content color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `drawerContainerColor` in the `ModalDrawerSheet`

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet (drawerContainerColor=Red){
            //..
        }
    }
    //...
 )
```

[image]

Comment: What about drawerContentColor? it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationDrawerItemDefaults

```
NavigationDrawerItem(
colors = NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.colors(
                                                selectedContainerColor = Color.White,
                                                unselectedContainerColor = Color.White
                                            )
```